# PHP htmlspecialchars encode

Tags: php

I must mention first of all. Im newbie in php, so pls understand me.

I have a difficult with that form..

```
    <form action="something.php" method="get">
    <input type="text" name="something">
    <input type="submit" value="send">
```

In "something.php" i have that line of code:

```
   <?php
   $something = $_GET["something"];
   ?>
```

When i write in html form, `<a href="#">asdqw</a>` for example, it's show me exactly that code...

Understand me.. Im newbie on that, and i want to learn..

I want to encode that, if somebody write that characters `< , > , $ , ^` etc, and to display something else, cuz i dont want to affect me.

I want to mention, i use and database.
What i write in that form, will be saved in database, and will be showed in another page, but and in url bar like: "http://some-site.com/page.php?something=something" . 
I hope to understand me, and forgive me for my bad language.
Im romanian, and i dont want to use translator.

Comment: Try http://php.net/htmlspecialchars?

Comment: i allready tryed that, but i unsucceed.

Comment: `$` and `^` are not html metacharacters anyways. they cannot "affect" you.

Comment: When you store to the database you don't want to store the encoded version, just use the escaping mechanisms of your database library. When you display the text you should use the escaping appropriate for the context you are displaying it in for example: `echo htmlspecialchars($row["data"]);`

Comment: Note that `htmlspecialchars()` will encode only characters that match, well, special characters for HTML. Let's say, if you have the string `¡Saludos desde Concepción!`, it will make it look exactly the same. `htmlspecialchars()` only encodes `&` as `&amp;`, `<` as `&lt;` and `>` as `&gt;` (also `"` as `&quot;` if you define ENT_NOQUOTES and `'` as `&#039;` if you define ENT_QUOTES). `htmlentities()`, on the other side, will transform your string into `&iexcl;Saludos desde Concepci&oacute;n!`, so all characters that have an HTML equivalent will be converted.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars):

```
$something = htmlspecialchars($_GET['something'], ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML5);
```

You should use this method for outputting data in a HTML context.

If you want to save the data into your database, you should rather use [MySQLi and Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli.prepare.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/de/book.pdo.php).


Here is a very nice answer showing important information about edge cases of Prepared Statements/PDO and `MySQLi::real_escape_string()`: [SQL injection that gets around mysql_real_escape_string()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)

Comment: No, don't do this on input, but on output. And I recommend against using `MySQLi::real_escape_string`.

Comment: @MarcelKorpel He *is* outputting the data in a link tag (see the question). Why do you recommend against using that method? I already recommended prepared statements. It's at least better than nothing.

Comment: `htmlspecialchars` should be enough. And there *are* edge cases where `real_escape_string` is not sufficient, can't find them now, though.

Comment: @MarcelKorpel I agree with *htmlspecialchars()*. The edge cases get introduced by either setting a different client encoding than the MySQL server's character set or by misusing the function (see the first post in the linked question). I've added a link to the answer.